# Python Page 404 not found

Tags: python, django, django-urls

New to Python, just starting up with a Issue reporting app which involves an API module.

**My Urls.py file:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', 

url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),

)
```

**My api.urls file**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('api.v1',
# Examples:
# url(r'^$', 'newproject.views.home', name='home'),
# url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

# authentication / session managemen
url(r'^auth/profile/me/$', 'account', name='my-account'),
url(r'^auth/profile/$', 'new_account', name='new-account'),
url(r'^auth/session/(?P<key>[a-z0-9]{64})/$', 'session', name='existing-session'),
url(r'^auth/session/$', 'new_session', name='new-session'),
....
```

**My Web Page 404 Error**

```
 Using the URLconf defined in newproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^api/

The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

I might be overlooking a mistake I made... 
Help Please?
Using Django 1.9.7

Comment: Assign a view to this `r'^$'` in API's `urls.py` file.

Comment: Here in the `include`, api must be the django app and `urls` will be the urls.py in that app. So basically file `api.urls` should be renamed to `urls.py` and kept in the newly created app `api`.

Comment: @JRodDynamite as I had earlier mentioned I'm new to Python and this is my first app. Kindly guide me on how to assign...

Comment: Add this line in API's `urls.py` file - `url(r'^$', 'some_view_function', name='some_view_function'),`. The `some_view_function` should be a function in `views.py` file of API app.

Comment: @JRodDynamite More questions following up on defining `some_view_function` in views.py...

Comment: What is the URL you are entering in the browser?

Comment: Local host on port 8000... Python's Default http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Answer (score 1):

replace `url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),`
 with `url(r'', include('api.urls')),`